# How to wait until Timer stops?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, wait

I'm trying to build a blackjack game using C#.
I have a casino class and player , card and deck classes which are objects of casino.
Casino deals a random card to a player with the function:

```
        public void giveRandomCardTo(Player P)
        {
            P.takeCard(this.deck.getRandomCard());
        }
```

this works nicely, but then I wanted to add an animation, like a closed card image moves to the player's card picturebox, using a timer. So I added this part to the function:

```
public void giveRandomCardTo(Player P)
        {
            while (_timerRunning) {/*wait*/ }
            this.currentDealingID = P.id;
            if (this.currentDealingID >= 0 && this.currentDealingID < this.NumberOfPlayers && this.currentDealingID!=10) 
            {//Checking the current player is not the dealer.
                this.MovingCard.Show(); //Moving card is a picture box with a closed card
                _timerRunning=true;
                T.Start();
            }
            P.takeCard(this.deck.getRandomCard());    
        }
```

and the Timer.Tick eventhandler of Timer T is:

```
public void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
              movingcardvelocity = getVelocityFromTo(MovingCard.Location, this.Players[this.currentDealingID].CardPBS[0].Location);
              double divide=5;
              movingcardvelocity = new Point((int)(movingcardvelocity.X / divide), (int)(movingcardvelocity.Y / divide));
              this.MovingCard.Location = new Point(this.MovingCard.Location.X + movingcardvelocity.X, this.MovingCard.Location.Y + movingcardvelocity.Y);
//Stop if arrived:
              double epsilon = 20;
              if (Distance(this.MovingCard.Location, this.Players[this.currentDealingID].CardPBS[0].Location) < epsilon) 
    {
    _timerRunning=false;  
    this.MovingCard.Hide();
    T.Stop();
    }
}
```

Timer works nicely, too. But when I'm dealing cards one after another, I have to wait until the first animation finishes. And the line `while(_timerRunning){/*wait*/}` in `void giveRandomCardTo` stucks the program in an infinite loop.

How can I make it wait until `bool _timerRunning = false`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait. Just call your method from `Tick` event handler without usage of `_timerRunning` flag. Stop timer and give card to player:

```
T.Stop(); 
this.MovingCard.Hide();
giveRandomCardTo(this.Players[this.currentDealingID]);
```

Also I'd created a method `IsCardArrivedTo(Point location)` to simplify conditional logic:

```
public void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var player = Players[currentDealingID];
     Point pbsLocation = player.CardPBS[0].Location;
     MoveCard();

     if (IsCardArrivedTo(pbsLocation)) 
     {        
        MovingCard.Hide();
        T.Stop();
        giveRandomCardTo(player);
     }
}

private bool IsCardArrivedTo(Point location)
{
    double epsilon = 20;
    return Distance(MovingCard.Location, location) < epsilon;
}

private void MoveCard()
{
   // calculate new location
   MovingCard.Location = newLocation;
}
```

*BTW* in C# we use CamelCasing for method names.

Comment: This worked. I have a lot of 1 or 2 line functions like this though, infact I started to avoid these, especially if i was to use them once. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @marvin it's better to use small methods with descriptive names, instead of dealing with big amount of code and writing comments like `//Stop if arrived:` :)

Comment: ok :) but there is still a problem with this solution, I modified the code so that player receives the card in timer.stop() so the giveRandomCardTo() became AnimateCard(){} but I still have for(i=0:i<numberofplayers;i++){animatecard(player[i]);} I mean I still have to wait somehow before entering the next animatecard(). What should I do?

Comment: @marvin simply start timer for each player - when timer stops, it will call `animatecard(player[i]);`

Comment: ok, I defined a Queue<Player> Dealing and at timer stop, it dequeues the next player and AnimateCard(Next). Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be helpful for you - [WaitHandle.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) method

There is an example you can reuse/modify

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have never understood threads, though :)

Comment: WaitOne - `Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal.` How this will help beside freezing ui?

Comment: It can help only if real work is being processed in separate thread